# Mount the FAT32 partition of the SDCard of which RPi is booting to edit cmdline.txt

Tags: sd-card, mount, cmdline.txt

I read some instructions for modifying the RPi that would require the `cmdline.txt` to be modified.

Unfortunately I have nothing but the Raspberry itself to mount the SD card, so I wonder whether I can mount the FAT32 partition of which the Raspberry booted, then modify the `cmdline.txt` from `nano` and then `reboot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to do this on the Pi, then the partition should be mounted, by default, in `/boot`. So just edit `/boot/cmdline.txt`

There should be no need to edit `cmdline.txt` in normal circumstances. There are lots of old instructions suggesting this, but virtually everything can be done more safely with `raspi-config`.

Comment: He may need to modify `/etc/fstab`. It looks like `/dev/mmcblk0p1` is mounted with default mount options (`/dev/mmcblk0p1    /boot    vfat    defaults    0    2`), but I don't know what they are for RPI. Do you know if `default` is `ro` or `rw`?

Comment: The options I needed are not available in raspi-config. Answer worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

yes you can mount the fat partition for temporarly reasons, otherwise use fstab

```
sudo mount -t vfat -o uid=root /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt
sudo nano /mnt/cmdline.txt
```

have fun

Comment: You probably mean `fstab`

Comment: thank you for commenting, i corrected the typo.